# c++ quicksort vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector, struct, lambda, qsort

I am having troubles using std::qsort on my vector of objects. (Note that this code is inside a loop)

```
std::vector<s_GridData> info = GetAllAdjacentObjInfoFromMap(FLOOR_OBJ, e_Object::eObject_WIRE, itr.getPos());

//No wires adjacent!
if (info.size() == 0) {
  continue;
}

std::cout << "Before sorting: ";
std::cout << info;

std::qsort(&info, info.size(), sizeof(s_GridData),
  [](const void *lhs, const void *rhs)->int {
    s_GridData gridLhs = *reinterpret_cast<const s_GridData*>(lhs);
    s_GridData gridRhs = *reinterpret_cast<const s_GridData*>(rhs);
    if (gridLhs.groupID < gridRhs.groupID) return -1;
    if (gridRhs.groupID < gridLhs.groupID) return 1;
    return 0;
  }
);

std::cout << "After sorting: ";
std::cout << info;
```

Here specifically in the quicksort code, it seems that the quicksort is erasing my `info`.
Is there something wrong with the lambda? Or is there another requirement for using qsort like an assignment operator overload. However `s_GridData` is simply a struct of integral values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use `std::sort`? Also, the first parameter to `qsort` should be a buffer with the data. The address of the vector won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the wrong arguments to `qsort()` (which is really a C function not originally in `namespace std`):

```
std::qsort(&info, ...
```

Right off the bat that's wrong, because `info` is a `std::vector` but `qsort()` requires a C-style array.  You can fix it this way:

```
std::qsort(info.data(), ...
```

Or before C++11:

```
std::qsort(&info[0], ...
```

However, the better solution is to use `std::sort()`, which is a *bona fide* C++ function giving type safety and other benefits.  It goes something like this:

```
sort(info.begin(), info.end(),
    [](const s_GridData& lhs, const s_GridData& rhs)->bool {
        return gridLhs.groupID < gridRhs.groupID;
    });
```

As you can see, the C++ way is more concise, and if your ordering is applicable across all your instances, you can define it separately (typically as an inline free function), in which case:

```
sort(info.begin(), info.end());
```

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that std::sort is actually more uptodate vs qsort. Infact I always had the assumption that qsort was for stdlib.

Comment: @ChristopherLeong `std::sort` is not more up to date, `std::sort` is C++, `qsort` is C